# overriding the equals method from the superclass

Tags: java, oop

Is a new implementation of the hashcode() method required when we override the equals() method from the superclass. The contract between equals() and hashcode() is kept.

Comment: no need to touch the hashcode() method

Comment: if contract between equals() and hashcode() is kept then no need to override hashcode()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `equals` and `hashCode` methods will be (just like any other method) inherited from the superclass.

If those are still appropriate for the subclass you can keep this as is.

There are examples in the JDK for this:

- `Stack` extends `Vector` extends `AbstractList`
- `Stack` just inherits `equals` from `Vector`
- `Vector` overrides `equals` from `AbstractList`, but only to add `synchronized` and then just calls `super.equals`.
- `ArrayList` also extends `AbstractList`, but it overrides `equals` with an implementation that follows the same logic, but can be more efficient because it knows that at least one of the participants is an `ArrayList`.

But keep in mind that

- you will now be comparing Super <-> Super, Super <-> Sub, Sub <-> Sub instances in all combinations with the same piece of code
- things like `this.getClass()` might return unexpected things when `this` can actually be a subclass

If that causes problems in your comparison logic is up to you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

Contract between equals and hashcode method need to be kept when your are going to use that class in hashing based collections, like hashmap, hashset etc which uses hashcode  method to calculate the hash index and equals method to check the equality. Otherwise you can ignore hashcode. Please refer below URL for more information on equals and hashcode method overriding in hashmap.
https://www.thetechnojournals.com/2019/10/why-hashmap-key-should-be-immutable-in.html